# Android WebView sound lags when app going background

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I'm developing an app that plays some music from a streaming website, I added a WebView with the following settings:

```
            WebSettings settings = webViewPlayer.getSettings();

            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(true);
            settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            settings.setAppCachePath("");
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            webViewPlayer.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            webViewPlayer.loadUrl(PLAYER_URL);
```

It works correctly and when app goes to background the sound is still playing (as needed), but it starts to lag badly, like it lost priority for downloading the streaming sound and it does it slower so sound is not smooth as when it is in foreground. Any clue what is happening here?
I haven't tested in another device for now but I think it is not device only related.
I tried to put onPause and onResume methods and I can't find other recomendations.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem and it happened on Android 10 with some types of music files, I don't know why, did you figure out what's the problem yet